# WindowServer crashes with external monitor on macOS High Sierra

Tags: display, macos, sleep-wake, crash

For now I have a following issue:

When I connect my external monitor (DELL P2418D) to my mac (MacBook Pro 15 2015), everything works fine, but after some long period of sleep(20-30 minutes or more), during wakeup WindowSever process crashes. It causes full logout from a system with finishing current session and closing all applications (this is annoying).

I have found some issues connected with WindowServer in the Internet, but it was not useful. For example: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8076643

What I have done:

- reset SMC
- reset PRAM
- boot to Safe mode

No changes

It may be important:

- I changed standard resolution of external monitor via SwitchResX App. From 2560x1440 to 3840x2160 (HiDPI FullHD).
- As far as I remember there was no crashes of WindowServer without external monitor.

Links to crash reports of WindowsServer:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1anOZVSfaeHUB1KoXFNCvyiXG-whpB4s3
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IfXNWPmlwumARgbETtMU5Ls8DXhGZKPc

Can any one help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does either uninstalling SwitchResX and running at 2560x1440 or turning off Graphics switching in the energy preferences fix the issue?

Comment: Can you clarify what actually happens *while* you're in Safe Mode? That is, if you're in Safe Mode and your MBP goes to sleep, do you still have the same problem?